# Ackerman Function in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I've setup my function but I'm not to sure why its not working the way I intend it to.

```
(define (ack m n) (if (= m 0) (+ n 1)

           (if (and (> m 0) (= n 0)) (ack (- m 1) 1)
                          
                 (if (and (> m 0) (> n 0)) (ack (- m 1) (- n 1))))))
```

This is what I'm following:

[Ackerman Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBphZ.png)

edit:

```
(define (ack m n) 
   (if (= m 0) 
       (+ n 1)
       (if (and (> m 0) (= n 0)) 
           (ack (- m 1) 1)
           (if (and (> m 0) (> n 0)) 
               (ack (- m 1) (ack m (- n 1)))))))
```

I'm an idiot, I was able to get it after looking at the Ackerman function again

Comment: Indent your code so it is easy to read.  Then look closely at the definition of the function: is your function actually doing the same thing in all cases (hint: what about the last case?)

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working the way I intend it to"? what error are you receiving, what input data are you using? Be aware that the Ackerman function is notorious for growing extremely fast, even with small inputs it'll take forever to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Indenting your code properly helps see whether its structure is proper:

```
(define (ack m n) 
   (if (= m 0) 
       (+ n 1)
       (if (and (> m 0) (= n 0)) 
           (ack (- m 1) 1)
           (if (and (> m 0) (> n 0)) 
               (ack (- m 1) (- n 1))
               ;; otherwise ......... what?
               ))))
```

An `if` expression better have both branches, the *consequent* and the *alternate*, or otherwise if the test fails and there's no alternate, under R5RS the result [is undefined](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r5rs-html/r5rs_6.html#SEC30). And [in Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html) such construct isn't even legal.

(that's before even reading inside your code, just from its structure).